# Reading and altering the to/cc/bcc fields programmatically in a Mail.app plugin

Tags: macos, apple-mail

Has anyone ever successfully figured out the method to alter the to, cc and bcc fields of an outgoing message in a Mail.app plugin? I've been looking through the header files trying to figure out exactly what I need to do to get the list of recipients of the message, and have the ability to alter them (specifically, to remove some recipients and switch the remaining recipients to be bcc'ed).

Note: I know where I would need to look to find out how to do this, but I've spent some time on that and there are a lot of different classes that do this and the amount of guesswork needed is nontrivial.  I'm merely hoping someone has gone through this already in the past and can save me from the duplicate effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

The window that you use to compose a message is a MailDocumentEditor, which inherits from DocumentEditor.  DocumentEditor has an instance variable called _headersEditor which is a HeadersEditor object.

HeadersEditor has instance variables for the to, cc and bcc fields, named _toField, _ccField and _bccField, respectively.  These are instances of AddressTextField.

There are methods that can get you the addresses that have been entered into the AddressTextField.  If you are familiar with Mail, addresses can appear in here in a few different ways. Some are just plain text addresses, some are tokens for address book entries (so they show up as tokens with the name, which you can right-click to get the email address).  You can create accessors for the NSMutableArray*s _stringsWithNoRecords and _stringsAwaitingRecords, as well as the NSMutableDictionary* _recordsForStrings.

However, to set the addresses of these fields, create an NSCell using initTextCell:(NSString *) with the email addresses you want in these fields.  Then, call the setCell: method on the AddressTextField.  This will replace the contents of that field with your NSString in the NSCell.

Comment: Note: I've spoken too soon about getting the previously entered addresses.  Getting _stringsWithNoRecords will get the plain text email addresses (assuming that you've done command+s to save a draft first) but it sometimes duplicates. It also doesn't get the tokenized email addresses (i.e. ones that it recognizes). Furthermore, neither _stringsAwaitingRecords nor _recordsForStrings gives me any content (at least in Lion). I'll update the answer when I know more about this.  However, if you know to whom you're sending already, you can use setCell: to set the contents of the AddressTextField.

Comment: Update: I figured out how to get the recipients' addresses as strings!  just call the backEnd method on the MessageEditor, which has the methods toRecipients, ccRecipients and bccRecipients.  These are NSArrays of MessageAddressee objects, whose address method will give you the NSString address.